# creating an NSImage from downloaded NSData in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, nsdata, nsimage

So I'm using the AlamoFire library to download an image url which returns the **NSData** object 'avatarData'. But I can't figure out how to save this information **into an NSImage** object for later use in a view.

Here's my best attempt at **converting to NSImage**:

```
private func GetAvatar(avatarHash: String) {
    let avatar = "https://trello-avatars.s3.amazonaws.com/\(avatarHash)/30.png"
    Alamofire.request(.GET, avatar)
        .response {(request, response, avatarData, error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                self.handleConnectionError(error)
            } else {
                println(avatarData)
                let backgroundImage = NSImage(avatarData: NSData)
            }
    }

}
```

I've tried a couple variations of the syntax, but I usually end up with the errors:

`expected member name or constructor call after type name`

and/or

`missing argument for parameter 'flipped' in call`

---

Here's a sample of the `println(avatarData)`

`Optional(<89504e47 0d0a1a0a 0000000d 49484452 0000001e 0000001e 08020000 01c35509 63000008 72494441 5448c705 ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`avatarData` is an NSData, `NSImage` has a constructor that takes an `NSData`, just use that:

```
let image = NSImage(data:avatarData!)
```

Comment: Thanks David! The XCode compiler errored on this saying that it couldn't 'implicitly downcast avatarData to type NSData. Explicitly casting the type with `let backgroundImage = NSImage(data: avatarData as NSData)` did it. I don't know if there's a downside  or anything to doing this though..

Comment: I've never used Alamodome, so don't really know, but from naming I'd assume it's always an MSData.  For safety you should probably wrap it in an if let statement

Answer (score 1):

You could use a class I wrote that simplifies asynchronously downloading images from the web and displaying them using NSImageView and Swift (ported from an Objective-C version by someone else):
https://github.com/davecom/DKAsyncImageView

Comment: Looks like a really cool library davecom, it doesn't fit my needs on this project but I'll definitely consider it in the future :)